# Faulty if statement (beginner)

Tags: if-statement, cs50

I'm on week 2 of cs50 edx, and keep getting the following error when trying to compile:

> caesar.c:23:7: error: expected expression if (isalpha(encryptme[p]) =
>   true){
>         ^

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc !=2) { 
    printf("ERROR: Must pass exactly two command line arguments!\n");
    return 1;}  

   string num = argv[1];
   int i = atoi(num);

   printf("plaintext: ");

   string encryptme = get_string();

   printf("cyptertext: ");

   for (int p = 0; p <= strlen(encryptme); p++)(
      if ( isalpha(encryptme[p]) = true){
      printf("%c",encryptme[p]+i%26);
      }
   )
}
```

Stared at this for over an hour, have searched for over an hour, please find my undoubtedly idiotic error!

Comment: Also - this is supposed to create a relatively simply cypher after prompting the user for an string to encrypt. The command line is supposed to accept two arguments, the first calling the program and the second being a # to base the cypher off of.

Comment: Change this `if ( isalpha(encryptme[p]) = true)` **to** `if ( isalpha(encryptme[p]) == true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `==` instead of `=`.

The former is an equality test; the latter is an assignment.

It's better not to compare with `true` however. Best is to just say

```
if (isalpha(encryptme[p]))
```

Also, be careful of even using `true` in C. It is not supported in all versions of C. I'm not sure what is in `cs50.h`. Maybe `true` is in there, maybe not....

I'd do it like this:

```
for (int p = 0; p <= strlen(encryptme); p++) {
    if (isalpha(encryptme[p])) {
        printf("%c", encryptme[p] + i % 26);
    }
}
```

Cleaned up some spacing and indenting to be more conventional. (Also you should accept jdow's answer since that was where the detection of `(` for `{` was made first.

Comment: Thank you - that's definitely an error, but I fixed and recompiled and still get the same error message.

Comment: Interesting, but cs50.h must incorporate. It compiles after making the other corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop
`for (int p = 0; p <= strlen(encryptme); p++)(` has it's statements enclosed in `()` rather than `{}`

Comment: Thank you. This, along with the help from Ray, made it compile.

Comment: Glad to help, click to accept the answer if it worked.